# Executing a PUT method in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have inherited a code-base that uses ASP.NET MVC 3. I'm learning it as I go. This project appears to expose an API of the format "/svcs/orders/". There is a method that is already written in a file located in MyProject.Areas.svcs.Controllers.OrdersController. That controller looks like the following:

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
{
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Put)]
  public ActionResult AddOrder(OrderModel data)
  {
    // Do Stuff...

    var result = GetResult();
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to call this method via JQuery. I know that I can reference the service via an address of "/svcs/orders/". But I'm not sure how to "PUT" data to the service. How do I populate the OrderModel parameter that is expected by the AddOrder method? Its so bizarre to me. Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
var productID = $("#hidProductID").val();
var quantity = $("#txtQuantity").val();

$.ajax({
  url: '/svcs/orders',
  type: 'PUT',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("There was an error.");
  }
});
```

Thank you so much for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `OrderModel` in the data property of ajax options in the form of `JSON` object.

```
var productID = $("#hidProductID").val();
var quantity = $("#txtQuantity").val();

$.ajax({
  url: '/svcs/orders',
  type: 'PUT',
  data: {
     productID: productID,
     quantity: quantity
  },
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("There was an error.");
  }
});
```

Comment: When I do this, I receive a 500 error. Why would this happen? I have it so my method isn't doing anything other than returning "ok".

Comment: Set breakpoint in your controller method AddOrder and see if it even gets hit, and if it does inspect the OrderModel data item using the debugger. If it doesn't get hit you have a problem in routing. You should also post the data type of `OrderModel` if you want us to help you build the appropriate object on the client side with JS.